# ArrayList with Multiple Values c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, arraylist

I am unsure whether this is possible with an ArrayList or a Dictionary or whether it would be something else, if so I wonder where you could point me in the right direction...

Can you have an ArrayList with Multiple Values i.e.

```
ArrayList weather = new ArrayList();
weather.Add("Sunny", "img/sunny.jpg");
weather.Add("Rain", "img/Rain.jpg);
```

To then assign to controls like below.

```
if (WeatherValue = 0)
{
   Label1.Text = weather[0].ToString;
   Image1.ImageUrl = weather[0].ToString;
}
```

Or can I do this with a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Cloudy", "../img/icons/w0.png");  //[0]
dict.Add("Rain", "../img/icons/w1.png");    //[1]  

Label1.Text = dict[0].VALUE1;    //So this would get Cloudy
Image.ImageUrl = dict[0].VALUE2; //This would get ../img/w0.png
```

How do you call the values of a dictionary separately using [0], and [1] ? etc

Comment: Theres no reason to still use `ArrayList`, use the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason to still use `ArrayList`, use the [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you keep compile time safety and you don't need to cast everything.

In this case you should create a custom class:

```
public class Weather
{
    public double Degree { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this readable and maintainable code:

```
List<Weather> weatherList = new List<Weather>();
weatherList.Add(new Weather { Name = "Sunny", IconPath = "img/sunny.jpg" });
weatherList.Add(new Weather { Name = "Rain", IconPath = "img/Rain.jpg" });

if (WeatherValue == 0) // whatever that is
{
    Label1.Text = weatherList[0].Name;
    Image1.ImageUrl = weatherList[0].IconPath;
}
```

**Update**: according to your edited question. A dictionary doesn't make much sense because you can't access it via index(it has no order) but only via key. Since that would be the weather-name you have to know it beforehand. But it seems that you don't have it.

So either loop all key-value pairs in the dictionary and use the key for the name and the value for the path or simply use a real class which would be much better.

If you don't want to create a class there's only one thing that comes to my mind, the [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> weatherList = new List<string, string>();
weatherList.Add(Tuple.Create("Sunny", "img/sunny.jpg"));
weatherList.Add(Tuple.Create("Rain", "img/Rain.jpg"));

if (WeatherValue == 0) // whatever that is
{
    Label1.Text = weatherList[0].Item1;
    Image1.ImageUrl = weatherList[0].Item2;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps turn 'Name' into an enum called weatherType?

Comment: @sr28: sure, there are many ways to improve or extend this class. It should just give OP an idea.

Comment: I would also create my own class. But then there's also the Tuple class which can be used

Comment: @FredrikRedin: added the tuple approach

Comment: Thanks I have got this working using a Class and a List like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> weather =   new Dictionary<string, string>();

values.Add("Sunny", "img/sunny.jpg");
values.Add("Rain", "img/Rain.jpg");
```

The simplest way to call element in a dictionnary is using foreach loop

```
foreach (var pair in weather )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",pair.Key,pair.Value);
    }
```